# bash question about if and then

Tags: bash, shell, test, whitespace

I'm writing this in my script. It has other parts but I'm getting stuck on this part only.

```
if [[$# == $year $month $day  ]] ; then
    cal $day $month $year
fi
```

When I run this it give me this msg:

```
[[3: command not found
```

So what is the problem? is it a syntax or actual command?

Here's the rest of my script if that helps:

```
year=$(echo "$year" | bc)
month=$(echo "$month" | bc)
day=$(echo "$day" | bc)

if [[$# == $year $month $day  ]] ; then    
    cal $day $month $year
fi
```

Comment: [This](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/41104) should help you leaps.

Comment: The if stmt:is all wrong. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: im trying to use cal command in script to validate date and this is what my conditions are

Comment: if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        echo Usage: chkdate year month day
        exit 0
fi

Comment: if [[ "$year" == "" || "$month" == "" || "$day" == "" ]]; then
        # Not enough data!
        echo Usage: chkdate year month day
        exit 1
fi
if [[ $month == 2 && $(($year%100)) == 0 ]]; then
        if [[ $(($year%400)) == 0 ]]; then
                isLeapYear=1
        else
                isNotLeapYear=1
        fi
elif [[ $month == 2 && $(($year%4)) == 0 ]]; then
        isLeapYear=1
else
        isNotLeapYear=1
fi

Comment: if [[ $month == 2 && $day -gt 28 && $isNotLeapYear ]]; then
        # Not Leap year!
        echo Usage: chkdate year month day
        exit 2
fi
if [[ $month == 2 && $day -gt 29 && $isLeapYear ]]; then
        # Invalid day!
        echo Usage: chkdate year month day
        exit 3
fi

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a space after the square brackets, `[[`.

```
if [[ $# == $year $month $day ]] ; then    
    cal $day $month $year
fi
```

Also as you have it written that won't work. You have compare `$#` and `$year $month $day` as a string, or something else entirely. Perhaps:

```
if [[ "$#" == "$year$month$day" ]] ; then    
    cal $day $month $year
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few problems with this.

1. You need a space after the `[[`:

   ```
   [[ $# == $year $month $day ]]
   ```
2. `$#` is not what you think it is. It is the number of arguments passed to a script or a function. It looks like you think it is actually the list of arguments.
3. `==` compares strings, you're giving it a list of sorts. To compare the list of arguments passed to your script with `$day` `$month` `$year`, you would do something like this:

   ```
   [[ "$@" == "$day $month $year" ]]
   ```
4. <del>`cal` does not work that way</del>. My `cal` does not work that way but [apparently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159941/bash-question-about-if-and-then/160027?noredirect=1#comment262401_160027) some newer versions do. I have no idea what you're actually trying to do but it won't work. Are you perhaps looking for `date -d "$day/$month/$year"`? For example

   ```
   $ date -d "08/10/2014"
   Sun Aug 10 00:00:00 CEST 2014
   ```

   Or, if you want to show the calendar of a specific month:

   ```
   $ cal 10 2014
       October 2014      
   Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
             1  2  3  4  
    5  6  7  8  9 10 11  
   12 13 14 15 16 17 18  
   19 20 21 22 23 24 25  
   26 27 28 29 30 31
   ```

Comment: Actually, the version of `cal` from util-linux 2.21.2 (present in Cygwin 1.1.2) ***does*** work that way: `Usage:` / `cal [options] [[[day] month] year]`.

Comment: @G-Man ah, perhaps. Mine (util-linux 2.20.1-5.5) does not. Thanks.