# Echo out lines of script before running them

Tags: bash, shell-script, debugging

Is there a way to run scripts in `bash` that makes it so that it prints each line of the script before executing it?  This would be really useful to me for debugging...

```
$./myscript.sh
echo "Hello"
Hello
```

I would be able to see exactly how far my script has gotten, and what it is doing.

Comment: Take a look at: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329

Comment: you can debug the whole script with `sh -x myscript.sh`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can enable/disable this feature through the use of the `set` command, and the option `-x/+x`.

> **-x** - After  expanding  each simple command, for command, case command, select command, or arithmetic for command, display the expanded value of PS4, followed by the command and its expanded arguments or associated word list.

`-x` enables it, `+x` disables it.

#### Example

*sample script*

```
$ cat ~/myscript.sh 
#!/bin/bash

set -x
echo "Hello"
```

*sample output*

```
$ ~/myscript.sh 
+ echo Hello
Hello
```

Comment: To expand on this, you can get really creative and set `PS4='${LINENO}+`, which will also tell you which line of the script expands to what is being run.  For the above, example, the output would be `4+ echo Hello` followed by `Hello`.