# Inserting variables in a file path on GNU linux (SLES 11)

Tags: linux, bash, variable-substitution

I am tryin to insert 3 variables to build a path, but unable to get it .

I am trying the below

```
log_path="/vol02/logs/$dname/logs/103602_$msname/${msname}_start.log"

dname=cfp
msname=cfp003
```

i get the below output.

```
_start.logs/cfp/logs/103602_cfp003
```

I need

```
/vol02/logs/cfp/logs/103602_cfp003/cfp003_start.log
```

Comment: Place the `dname` and `msname` declarations before the `log_path` declaration, or use single quotes for the `log_path` declaration.

Comment: yes the declarations are before the log_path declaration , and i have used ' quotes instead of , it gives me the output..  /vol02/logs/$dname/logs/103602_$msname/${msname}_start.log doesnt give the variable values

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dname=cfp
msname=cfp003
log_path="/vol02/logs/${dname}/logs/103602_${msname}/${msname}_start.log"
echo "$log_path"
```

Output:

```
/vol02/logs/cfp/logs/103602_cfp003/cfp003_start.log
```

Comment: tried exactly what u said , it still gives the same old output.#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ $((head -1 details.csv)|(cut -d',' -f1,1)) == 'hostname' ]; then
#sed -i '1d' details.csv
echo 'Hello there....'
fi
for full_rec in $(cat details.csv)
do
echo $full_rec
hname=`echo $full_rec | cut -d',' -f1,1`
dname=`echo $full_rec | cut -d',' -f2,2`
msname=`echo $full_rec | cut -d',' -f3,3`
log_path="/vol02/logs/${dname}/logs/103602_${msname}/${msname}_start.log"
echo "$log_path"
echo $hname $dname $msname
done     output is still _start.logs/cfp/logs/103602_cfp003

Comment: Feel free to check and fix your code with http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: still doesnt work, any alternatives?

Comment: Some ways to debug your script and see content of variables: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: looks like the problem is in the variable $msname , it extracts the value along with a \r , how do i get rid of \r from the variable ?

Comment: Try to remove `\r` before it gets into your variable msname:  `msname=$(echo $full_rec | cut -d',' -f3,3 | tr -d "\r")`