# What's wrong with my elif statements in this rock paper scissors game I'm making

Tags: bash, scripting

making a rock paper scissors game to learn better bash. For some reason it's not liking my elif statements and I can't figure out why. Also if there are any better ways of doing this let me know, thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash

#rock beats scissors, scissors beats paper, paper beats rock, 
printf "Welcome to rock paper scissors. Type 'r', 'p', or 's' to start: "

#get users selection
read user

#detect input and assign it to a num that will be used to check against computer.
if [[ $user == [rR] || $user == "Rock" || $user == "rock" ]]
  then
    user="r"
elif [[ $user == [sS] || $user == "scissors" || $user == "Scissors" ]]
  then
    user="s"
elif [[ $user == [pP] || $user == "paper" || $user == "Paper" ]]
  then
    user="p"
else
    printf "Not a valid submission, you entered: $user\n"
fi

#get random number between 1 and 9
comp=$(shuf -i 1-9 -n 1)

#detect what number it was and assign either r p s to it. 
if ((1<=$comp && $comp<=3))
  then 
    comp="r"
    printf "Rock\n"
elif ((4<=$comp && $comp<=6))
  then
    comp="s"
    printf "Scissors\n"
elif ((6<=$comp && $comp<=9))
  then
    comp="p"
    printf "Paper\n"
else
    echo "not in range?"
fi

#find out who won
if [[ $user == $comp ]]
  then
    echo "same!"
elif [[ $user == "r" && $comp == "p" ]]
    echo "user rock comp paper COMP WINS"
elif [[ $user == "p" && $comp == "r" ]]
    echo "comp rock user paper USER WINS"
elif [[ $user == "s" && $comp == "r" ]]
    echo "user scissors comp rock COMP WINS"
elif [[ $user == "r" && $comp == "s" ]]
    echo "user rock comp scissors USER WINS"
elif [[ $user == "p" && $comp == "s" ]]
    echo "user paper comp scissors COMP WINS"
elif [[ $user == "s" && $comp == "p" ]]
    echo "user scissors comp paper USER WINS"
else
    echo "something is borked"
fi
```

And I get this error:

```
./rps.sh: line 49: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
./rps.sh: line 49: `elif [[ $user == "p" && $comp == "r" ]]'
```

Comment: Missing your "then"s

Comment: Pro tip: shellcheck.net

Comment: Mmmmmmmmm crap. thanks for that site. I can give you credit if you wanna submit an answer!

Comment: It'll be a bit before I could write something up. FYI also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/41104

Comment: I probably shouldn't have answered in the comments anyway, so I'd be in favor of just closing this Q as a typo-fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much more readable way to do this sort of this is with a `case` statement:

```
move=''
while [[ -z "$move" ]]; do
   echo "Please specify paper, scissors, or rock.  >"
   read userinput
   case "$userinput" in
      [Rr]*)
         move="rock"
         ;;
      [Pp]*)
         move="paper"
         ;;
      [Ss]*)
         move="scissors"
         ;;
      *)
         echo "Invalid input."
         ;;
   esac
done
```

You can do something similar with your randomly selected computer player's move and for outcome determination.