# Why can't I execute this script?

Tags: bash, scripting

I am trying to execute a script to determine its system running time and potentially fix its problems.

If I type:

```
{hostname@bankofamerica]$ ./xx-xxx-xxxxx.sh 
[sudo] password for hostname: 
_
```

It has been like this for a while! I am guessing the system is still running, but I don't see the problems. How can I find out about the problems here? Any tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: We can't possibly help you out unless you add the contents of the script to the question. There is no telling from what you have provided so far what the problem might be.

Comment: See this question for general tips on debugging bash scripts [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155551/how-to-debug-a-bash-script)

Comment: You *did* execute the script; it apparently has a sudo'd command in it.

Comment: Your username is `hostname` and your hostname is `bankofamerica`?!?

Answer (score 1):

No expert here, but it would appear it's waiting for you to type in the password.

Comment: I typed the password, and it's still on __ page. Hmm!! I guess this script is taking a long time to load, but I can't find the reason why!!