# How can I run script for all directories?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, imagemagick

Suppose I am at the main directory which contains script.sh and subdirectories, each of subdirectories contain images.
The script.sh is a script for resizing images. I want to apply this script to every subdirectories, so after searching for solution I created another script which is

```
SAVEIFS=$IFS #Since the subdirectories contain whitespaces in their name
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
for d in ./*; do
  if [ -d "$d" ]; then
    echo "$d" && cp ./script.sh ./$d/script.sh && cd "$d" && exec sh ./script.sh && cd ..
  fi
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

The problem is this script stops after it's done at the first subdirectory. How can I make it runs for all subdirectories? Or are there better way to make script.sh runs for all subdirectories?

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` to the rescue!

```
CURDIR=`pwd`
IFS=$'\n'
for d in $(find . -type d); 
do 
    cd $CURDIR/"$d"
    $CURDIR/script.sh
done
```

Even better... strip the "all files in the directory" stuff from your script, and:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for f in $(find . -type f); 
do 
    ./script.sh "$f"
done
```

Comment: See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice).  Better to use some variant of `find . -type d -execdir /path/to/script.sh {} \;` (with the variations depending on what, if any, args you want to pass to `script.sh`)

Comment: Thanks, @cas.  I find the loop much more comprehensible than having to deal with `{} \;` and `{} +` and it's thousand variations.

Comment: Did you read the linked Q&A?  My comment wasn't about comprehensibility, or the fact that shell loops are the slowest way of looping over any text input, or even about writing fewer lines of code to do the same thing, it was about the fact that there are risks in looping over `find`'s output .  Risks that aren't necessary because `find` has `-exec` and `-execdir`.

Comment: @cas I understand that.  But for me, now, screwing up `find` esoterica is an existential problem, whereas looping over it's results aren't.