# How redirecting debug output to a file

Tags: shell-script, shell

I use `-x` for debug info while executing the shell script.

How can I redirect debug info only to a file?

Example script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo OK
echo NO
```

i will get the below result when i run in debug mode

```
+ echo OK
OK
+ echo NO
NO
```

I would like to redirect only the debug info to a file.

```
+ echo OK
+ echo NO
```

And runtime output should print on the screen.

```
OK
NO
```

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/117549

Answer (score 9):

Try this,

```
 sh -x script.sh 2> out.log
```

Comment: +1 for how simple and clear this is compared to the resource marked duplicated.