# bash: expecting number addition with +=. Not exactly sure if the operand is a number

Tags: bash

I am trying to detect armstrong numbers with this code:

```
declare -i INPUT=$1


arr=($(fold -w1 <<< "$INPUT"))
for index in "${!arr[@]}"
do
  armstrong_sum+=$((${arr[index]}**${#arr[@]}))
done


echo "$armstrong_sum"
```

Commands to run the code: `./armstrong_sum 9`, `armstrong_sum 10` and `./armstrong_sum 153`

Output: `9`, `10` and `112527`

Expected output: `9`, `1` and `153`

*An armstrong number is a number that is the sum of its own digits each raised to the power of number of digits*

**More importantly I want to be able to debug the script myself. Not exactly sure how one debugs in bash. Like get type of operand and see pause iteration at each step**

Comment: your expected output doesnt make sense - by your own definition 153 should return 729

Comment: `1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 153`. This my expected output, i.e an armstrong number

Comment: Your second question (the bold part) already has an answer, easily found by searching: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155551/how-to-debug-a-bash-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in `man bash` (emphasis mine)

> **When += is applied to a variable for which the
>          integer  attribute  has  been  set, value is evaluated as an arithmetic
>          expression and added to the variable's current  value,  which  is  also
>          evaluated.**   When  +=  is  applied  to an array variable using compound
>          assignment (see Arrays below), the variable's value is not unset (as it
>          is when using =), and new values are appended to the array beginning at
>          one greater than the array's maximum  index  (for  indexed  arrays)  or
>          added  as  additional  key-value  pairs  in an associative array.  **When
>          applied to a string-valued variable, value is expanded and appended  to
>          the variable's value.**

You are clearly getting the latter, i.e.

```
1 + 125 + 27 = 112527
```

So you have a couple of options - either declare `armstrong_sum` as integer

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i INPUT=$1
declare -i armstrong_sum=0

arr=($(fold -w1 <<< "$INPUT"))
for index in "${!arr[@]}"
do
  armstrong_sum+=$(( ${arr[index]}**${#arr[@]} ))
done


echo "$armstrong_sum"
```

or ensure arithmetic evaluation by surrounding the whole expression in `((` and `))` i.e.

```
(( armstrong_sum += ${arr[index]}**${#arr[@]} ))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use https://www.shellcheck.net (I use it as syntactic vim plugin making a crude [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment))

I'd go with this;

```
#!/bin/bash

P="$(echo -n "$1" | wc -c)"
SUM=0;
for X in $(echo "$1" | fold -w 1) ; do
    SUM=$(echo "$SUM+($X^$P)" | bc );
done
echo "$SUM"
```

It's not "pure" bash but I find the power of bash is the wide selection of tools, and prioritizing legibility.

for stack traces if you add the following to the top of all your scripts it will inform you of errors;

```
set -e
trap 'echo "ERROR: $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO $BASH_COMMAND" >&2' ERR
```

it will stop the script on the error line, make output like

```
test.sh: line 7: no: command not found
ERROR: test.sh:7 no + 5
```

instead of (potentially silently) ignoring errors.
Use -x for debugging;

```
bash -x armstrong.sh 222
++ echo -n 222
++ wc -c
+ P=3
+ SUM=0
++ fold -w 1
++ echo 222
+ for X in $(echo "$1" | fold -w 1)
++ echo '0+(2^3)'
++ bc
+ SUM=8
+ for X in $(echo "$1" | fold -w 1)
++ echo '8+(2^3)'
++ bc
+ SUM=16
+ for X in $(echo "$1" | fold -w 1)
++ echo '16+(2^3)'
++ bc
+ SUM=24
+ echo 24
24
```