# How to debug/trace bash function?

Tags: bash, debugging, tracing

I have a bash script `myscript.sh`, which has a bunch of functions inside. To run one function, I would write

```
source myscript.sh; myfunction
```

How debug such a function?

Comment: Related: [How to debug a bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155551/how-to-debug-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 6):

Just add these line before section you want to debug.

`set -v -x -e`

and to disable it.

`set +v +x +e`

Answer (score 2):

enable debugging in your script and output debugging for functions with `functrace`.

```
set -x
set -o functrace
```

Comment: Is there any way to direct the output this produces to a log file?

Comment: @BrittonKerin `yourScript.sh 2>1& >output_to_file`.

Answer (score 1):

You should also in Bash be able to use:

```
$ set -xT
```

which enables function trace
and

```
$ set +xT
```

to disable.

Also, with reference to another posted answer, I don't recommend using -v for debugging (verbose mode) unless you are checking a script/set of shell commands for syntax.  One other (general) solution that is sometimes useful is making use of the `-n` option in conjunction with `-x`.  This will "run" a script/commands without actually doing the last step of running a command.  This can often let you pick up difficult errors in shell expansions and the like without causing unwanted mayhem.