# Unix. Run script across multiple dirs on specific files, where pathname has regex

Tags: bash, regular-expression, for

I want to make a bash script (split.sh) that iterates across multiple dirs with same suffix, and then runs a function for specific files within them. I am almost there:

```
#!/bin/bash
path="/mypath/MAP-9-[0-9][0-9][0-9]"

for filename in $path/*bam; do
    [ -e "$filename" ] || continue
    echo $filename
        for chrom in `seq 1 22` X Y
        do
        samtools view -bh $filename $chrom > $path/$chrom.bam
        samtools index > $path/$chrom.bam; 
        done
done
```

However, I get many messages of this kind: "split.sh: line 12: /mypath/MAP-9-[0-9][0-9][0-9]/6.bam: No such file or directory"

The problem is that the script is not recognizing the "[0-9][0-9][0-9]" regex part of the pathname. I also tried adding escape characters to the square brackets without success. It must be a very simple solution, but I am not able to solve it.

This is an extract of the tree command's output:

```
|-- [[
|-- MAP-9-001
|   |-- MAP-9-001.bam
|   `-- MAP-9-001.bam.bai
|-- MAP-9-003
|   |-- MAP-9-003.bam
|   `-- MAP-9-003.bam.bai
|-- MAP-9-005
|   |-- MAP-9-095.bam
|   `-- MAP-9-095.bam.bai
|-- split.sh
```

Comment: Take a look: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/mypath/MAP-9-[0-9][0-9][0-9]/*.bam` is a shell glob, or [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#index-filename-expansion) expression. It expands to a list of matching files - you can use that to iterate over your input files, but you can't expect it to work as a "per iteration" wildcard to generate the corresponding output files. I think what you probably want instead is to generate each output file from the corresponding loop variable `$filename`, as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

for filename in /mypath/MAP-9-[0-9][0-9][0-9]/*.bam; do
    [ -e "$filename" ] || continue
    echo "$filename"
    for chrom in {1..22} X Y; do
        samtools view -bh "$filename" "$chrom" > "${filename%/*}/${chrom}.bam"
        samtools index > "${filename%/*}/$chrom.bam"
    done
done
```

The shell [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#index-parameter-expansion) `${filename%/*}` expands to the value of `$filename` with the shortest trailing substring `/*` removed; it thus gives you the dirname of each input file, to which you can then add the `$chrom.bam` to form each output file in turn.

Answer (score 3):

Don't be confused by `glob` vs `regex` (you use `glob` here):

Globs are shell patterns that can be used for matching strings or expanding pathnames:

```
[[ $name = Bob* ]]
rm *.txt
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob

A corrected version of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in /path/MAP-9-[0-9][0-9][0-9]/*bam; do
    [[ -e $filename ]] || continue
    echo "$filename"
    for chrom in {1..22} X Y; do
        samtools view -bh "$filename" "$chrom" > "$(dirname "$filename")/$chrom.bam"
        samtools index "$(dirname "$filename")/$chrom.bam"
    done
done
```

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words
> [when-is-double-quoting-necessary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

---

> `[[` is a bash keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the `[` command. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals. Unless you're writing for POSIX sh, I recommend `[[`

Comment: Thank you @Gilles for your info and help. Unfortunatelly I am getting the same messages. Yes, I am sure that it should not be "${filename##*/}/$chrom.bam"

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work either with your latest revision

Comment: If it doesn't work, your glob is invalid, correct it. Or provide the output of the `tree` command by editing your post

Comment: Hi @Gilles, I just provided it. Thank you